# How to create running text with jlabel?

Tags: java, text, netbeans, jlabel, graphical-programming

Let's just say i have a jlabel with a text in it. And i want the text keep changing every second to the left just like running text on the billboard.

Is it possible? if yes, how?

Comment: This is commonly called a "marquee effect" btw, and yes, as with everything else, this is very possible. Do you know how to move text or a JLabel?

Comment: yes i know how.

Comment: Then what's stopping you from translating that knowledge to.makijg scrolling text?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should use `javax.swing.Timer` to schedule `JLabel` updates. Please, see simplified code snippet below:

```
JFrame frame = new JFrame("Test");
frame.setSize(300, 300);
JLabel label = new JLabel("This is text!!!");
frame.add(label);
frame.setVisible(true);

final int labelWidth = 300;
final AtomicInteger labelPadding = new AtomicInteger();
Timer timer = new Timer(20, new ActionListener() {
    @Override
    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
        label.setBorder(new EmptyBorder(0, labelPadding.getAndIncrement() % labelWidth, 0, 0));
    }
});
timer.start();
```

Note that `AtomicInteger` is not necessary, but you need some `final` holder to be able to use it inside inner class or lambda.